# Youtube timed text

Tags: php, youtube

I want to get the timed text of a video from youtube. An example URL is provided below. I want to how to access the timed text in php. I have refereed https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference. But I have no idea of how to access this in PHP

For example consider the following video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX16OrIVfeQ&feature=relmfu

Comment: What do you mean by 'Timed Text'? Is it annotations or are you referring to the text that is shown at 00:09 in the video? if it's the latter I wouldn't of thought that would be possible as it's part of the video and not an annotation or other element inserted into the video via the youtube uploader.

Comment: i mean the interactive transcript. Not the one inside the video